# Calculating the mean for a subset of data based on multiple variables (for every combination)

Tags: r

I have a data set in the following form:

```
object.type    condition    date       replicate    value
object1        condition1   17/2/2014     1         5000
object1        condition1   17/2/2014     2         6000
object1        condition1   18/2/2014     1         5500
object1        condition1   18/2/2014     2         6300

object1        condition2   17/2/2014     1         5000
object1        condition2   17/2/2014     2         6000
object1        condition2   18/2/2014     1         5500
object1        condition2   18/2/2014     2         6300

object2        condition1   17/2/2014     1         5000
object2        condition1   17/2/2014     2         6000
object2        condition1   18/2/2014     1         5500
object2        condition1   18/2/2014     2         6300
etc.
```

What I would like to do is calculate the mean for subsets of an object, in a certain condition, for a certain date. So, for example, for object1, in condition1, on the 17th, the value would be `mean(c(5000, 5500))`. So, in the end I end up with a data.frame like this:

```
object.type    condition    date          value
object1        condition1   17/2/2014     5250
object1        condition1   18/2/2014     6150
object1        condition2   17/2/2014     5250
object1        condition2   18/2/2014     6150
object2        condition1   17/2/2014     5250
etc.
```

I could do this using nested loops (loop through all levels of object types, loop through all levels of conditions, loop through all levels of dates), but I'm new to R and what I have learnt is that vectorizing is the best method of approaching these problems. I just can't seem to figure out how I would go about it. Are there any functions that would be helpful here? Or a neater approach other than using three nested for loops that would need to iteratively (and inefficiently) extend a data frame?

Comment: Please help me understand: looking at your sample dataset at the top, for object1, condition1, date=17/2/2014, how is the average of 5000 and 6000 = 5250?

Comment: @jlhoward Ahh I knew I would slip up there but I didn't expect anybody to actually look at the values haha. Well spotted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(plyr)
ddply(data,~ object.type  +  condition ,summarise,average=mean(value))
```

Try the above from plyr package

Comment: Thanks! I'm not actually using the plyr library, but it set me on the right path to find [this article](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Manipulating_data/Summarizing_data/) and helped me understand all of the alternatives and advantages/disadvantages of each.

Answer (score 1):

Using `aggregate(...)`, and assuming your data is in `df`:

```
result <- aggregate(value ~ object.type + condition + date, df, mean)
result
#   object.type  condition      date value
# 1     object1 condition1 17/2/2014  5500
# 2     object2 condition1 17/2/2014  5500
# 3     object1 condition2 17/2/2014  5500
# 4     object1 condition1 18/2/2014  5900
# 5     object2 condition1 18/2/2014  5900
# 6     object1 condition2 18/2/2014  5900
```

If you need `result` in the original order,

```
result <- with(result,result[order(object.type, condition, date),])
result
#   object.type  condition      date value
# 1     object1 condition1 17/2/2014  5500
# 4     object1 condition1 18/2/2014  5900
# 3     object1 condition2 17/2/2014  5500
# 6     object1 condition2 18/2/2014  5900
# 2     object2 condition1 17/2/2014  5500
# 5     object2 condition1 18/2/2014  5900
```